# How does gcc -MMD write .d files?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compiler-construction

How does the gcc decide what files are to be listed as dependencies to an object file being produced, when it writes a .d file?

I'm seeing different .d files when sysroot path is absolute, and relative.

```
g++ --MMD --sysroot=absolute_path_to_sysroot -c -o file.o -MF file.d file.cpp
g++ --MMD --sysroot=relative_path_to_sysroot -c -o file.o -MF file.d file.cpp
```

I'm seeing a weird case, where, 
If the compiler path and --sysroot are absolute, then 2 additional header files are being listed as dependencies in the .d file.

If the --sysroot is relative, then 2 additional header files are not being listed as dependencies in the .d file anymore.

This made me wonder, what is the criterion, other than a header being #included, based on which, the .d files are actually written by the compiler, and how would sysroot affect this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, it is based on the actual directory where the file is found

The actual "make this a dependancy" happens here, where `sysp` is set a few lines above based on the directory that it is found in.

http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/libcpp/files.c?revision=206293&view=markup#l884

sysp gets set here:

http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/gcc/incpath.c?revision=206289&view=markup#l446

Now, it gets complicated if the same directory is both in `-I` and `-isystem` directories. In that case, it gets determined by whether the file is included with  `#include <name>` or `#include "name"` - those using `<>` are selected only if you use `-MD` or `-M`, etc, where the `-MMD` will ignore anything using `<>` (or in a directory marked with `sysp`).

Comment: hmm. That's most likely the reason. I took out the -I and left the compiler to choose the header only from sysroot, and the additional includes vanished. But, I still wonder why sysroot dir path being relative or absolute matters.

Comment: There is code to remove duplicates from `-I`, but it only removes identical entries. So depending on how your `-I` and `--sysroot` are specified, it may be that you are ending up with directories that actually point to the same thing, but are "written in different ways".